# Creating a grep command from scratch

Tags: c, operating-system

Hello I've been mixing and matching code around the internet in an attempt to make a command that recursively searches through a directory. I'm rather stuck right now. I only have two files in my directory at the moment (no subdirectories) and my print output keeps showing that I have more files than I actually have.

Here is my print output:

```
entered
entered
entered
enteredIF
entered
enteredIF
entered
enteredIF
entered
enteredIF
```

What I think it should do is print enteredIF just twice. Interestingly, there are eleven characters in my two files, and there are eleven print statements. Perhaps this is somehow related to my issue.

Could anyone please tell me how to just get the two print outputs (one for each file)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h> 
#include <dirent.h>
/* A process is a single process.  */ 
typedef struct process
{
  struct process *next;       /* next process in pipeline */
  char **argv;                /* for exec */
  pid_t pid;                  /* process ID */
  char completed;             /* true if process has completed */
  char stopped;               /* true if process has stopped */
  int status;                 /* reported status value */
} process;
/* A job is a pipeline of processes.  */
typedef struct job
{
  struct job *next;           /* next active job */
  char *command;              /* command line, used for messages */
  process *first_process;     /* list of processes in this job */
  pid_t pgid;                 /* process group ID */
  char notified;              /* true if user told about stopped job */
  struct termios tmodes;      /* saved terminal modes */
  int stdin, stdout, stderr;  /* standard i/o channels */
} job;

/* The active jobs are linked into a list.  This is its head.   */
job *first_job = NULL;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // char cwd[1024]; // buffer
    // char* sdirectory = getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)); 
    // printf("dir name: %s\n", sdirectory);

    int file_count = 0;
    DIR* dirp;
    struct dirent* entry;

    dirp = opendir(".");

    while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        printf("entered\n");
        if (entry-> d_type == DT_REG) {
        printf("enteredIF\n");
        file_count++;
    }

}
    closedir(dirp);
    printf("file count: %d\n", file_count);
```

}

Comment: Change your entered printf to: `printf("saw filename '%s'\n", entry->d_name);` and then you can see what filenames it thinks it is reading.  Perhaps you have more dot files than just `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your entered printf to: `printf("saw filename '%s'\n", entry->d_name);` and then you can see what filenames it thinks it is reading. Perhaps you have more dot files than just `.` and `..`. –  JohnH